# How to use SSL support in QuickFix/J

Tags: ssl, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I try to connect with SSL in QuickFix/J first time. I see an error that I did not see before. Error contains "Rejecting invalid message: quickfix.FieldException: Invalid MsgType" message. I put the error and my config file to question. Why is field 35 equals to U1, U2 etc.. Thanks.

This is for my market data connection. I will receive the market data. But I need to fix logon problem.

```
sender.conf

[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=0
FileLogPath=data/fix/log
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
SocketConnectHost=<>
SocketUseSSL=Y
CipherSuites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1
SocketKeyStore=/resources/config/x509cert.jks
SocketKeyStorePassword=<>
ResetOnLogon=Y

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=<>
TargetCompID=<>
SocketConnectPort=<>
Username=<>
Password=<>
```

```
FIX.event.log (some part)

Rejecting invalid message: quickfix.FieldException: Invalid MsgType, field=35: 8=FIX.4.49=4954435=U1634=349=<>52=20190712-12:54:42.85756=<>1=<>58=eyJ3bCI6IkZPUkVYNFlPVS1TVFAiLCJhY2NvdW50TnVtYmVyIjoiN21hcmtldHowMSIsImFjY291
bnRUeXBlIjoiVFJBREVSIiwiaW5zdHJ1bWVudHMiOlt7InRpdGxlIjoiJFVLMTAwIiwiY2Fub25p
Y2FsVGl0bGUiOiIkVUsxMDAvR0JQIiwibWVtbyI6IkZUU0UgMTAwIEluZGV4IENhc2giLCJwcmlt
YXJ5Q3VycmVuY3kiOiIkVUsxMDAiLCJiYXNlQ3VycmVuY3kiOiJHQlAiLCJtaW5BbW91bnQiOjEs......
20190712-12:54:43: Reject sent for Message 3: Invalid MsgType, field=35:35
20190712-12:54:43: MsgSeqNum too high, expecting 2 but received 4: 8=FIX.4.49=8735=134=449=<>52=20190712-12:54:43.13856=<>112=156293608313810=122
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer our question.  The problem has to be in your code.  I suspect you have not read the docs very well regarding how to set up your application.

Comment: It is not written that we should write a method for SSL connection in code. Could you a little bit explain possible solution? Where should I look? Isn't enough defining the config file for SSL? Thank you for reply. Regards.

Comment: I don't think your problem is SSL-related.  In fact, I think the SSL part might be correct, otherwise you wouldn't even get a connected socket.  I think you have written weird code in your QF app, and the problems are occurring *after* you've established the FIX connection.

Comment: Is the message that was rejected a message you received from your counterparty? Because message type U1 or U-whatever does not exist in FIX 4.4. Perhaps your counterparty is not abiding by FIX 4.4 messages?